# Does Array(String) allocates new space?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Does anyone know if the characters below allocates new space or not. My guess is it doesn't. Not sure if it's right.

```
let string = "abcdefg"
let characters = Array(string)
```

Some of my understanding below, correct me if I'm wrong

```
let string = "abcdefg"
var characters = Array(string) // no new space
print(characters[1]) // no new space
characters[1] = "a" // allocate new space upon changes
```

Asking because sometimes it's a hassle to deal with String.index, I would like to convert the String to an Array, which can be easy to access its elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal representation of a `String` is *not* an array of `Character`s.

(As of Swift 5, the preferred representation is a contiguous UTF-8 byte array, but there are other options, such as a “opaque” representation through function pointers for strings bridged from Objective-C. More information can be found in [UTF-8 String](https://swift.org/blog/utf8-string/) in the Swift Blog.)

On the other hand, `Array<Element>` uses contiguous memory of `Element` for its storage.

Therefore `Array(string)` *does* allocate new memory.

It can still be advantageous to convert a string to an array if frequent access to random characters of the same string is done, because subscripting is an `O(1)` operation for arrays, but not for strings.